# How to create an array using array_fill function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I want to create an array like below

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Here first element of the inner array will be incremental and second element will always be 0. The outer array length should be 30. I spent a lot of of time on it but couldn't solve it by my one. 
Can any one of you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: no not an assignment.I am not a college student. I am reading php functions and tried to achieve this through array_fill function. Just of curiosity @kevinabelita

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using `array_map()` and `range()`:

```
$o = array_map(function($a) { return array($a, 0); }, range(1, 30));
```

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UzzTH0)

Answer (score 1):

The array_fill() function creates an array where all elements are **identical**. You're asking for an array where the elements aren't all identical, so it's not something you can create simply by using array_fill()....

```
$array = array_fill(0, 2, array_fill(0, 2, 0)); 
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) { $value[0] = $key+1; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
<?php
function initArray() {
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
        $array[] = array($i, 0);
    }

    return $array;
}

// now call the initArray() function somewhere you need it
$myFancyArray = initArray();
?>
```